# CLCircularRegion - Arbitrary value for notifyOnEntry

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, clregion

I have a set of CLCircularRegions that are being monitored by the CLLocationManager. In viewDidLoad of my map view controller, I iterate through `monitoredRegions` on the location manager and create MKCircle overlays that correspond to the CLCircleRegions. The center coordinate and radius of each region (and the corresponding map overlay) are always correct and never change from their intended values. `notifyOnEntry`, however, seems to arbitrarily change between YES and NO every time I reload this view; only sometimes do the regions reflect the intended value for this property. Is there any reason this value would change, even when the other values remain constant? I do not manipulate the regions in any way after they are passed to the location manager.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Seems like an iOS bug to me.

Comment: Same here. Testing on iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: Same here on iOS 7.1.1

Comment: Same here, I see same thing in iOS 8.3. Is it really a bug?